# Cannot print in Chromium (snap - cups)

Tags: printing, snap, chromium

I'm having some printing problems in chromium (snap).
I have noticed that chromium is installing some new cups snap that should mirror the system cups in some way (proxy mode), but this is not working.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/new-interface-cups-for-all-snaps-which-print/29702

When I manually disconnect the cups snap from chromium, the printers does show up in the selections but I cannot submit the printjob:
[Image - Chromium print dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y6w3.png)

When `:cups` is connected the printers does not show up.

```
# snap logs cups
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36016]: + [ ! -e /var/snap/cups/872/var/run/proxy-mode ]
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36016]: + PID=36138
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36016]: + echo 36138
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36138]: + true
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36138]: +
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36016]: +
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36138]: sleep
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36016]: wait
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36138]:  3600
2022-12-23T09:39:56Z cups.cups-browsed[36016]:  36138

# snap connections cups
Schnittstelle            Plug                          Slot                      Notizen
avahi-control            cups:avahi-control            :avahi-control            -
cups                     -                             cups:cups                 -
cups-control             -                             cups:cups-server          -
cups-control             cups:cups-control             :cups-control             -
home                     cups:home                     :home                     -
network                  cups:network                  :network                  -
network-bind             cups:network-bind             :network-bind             -
network-manager-observe  cups:network-manager-observe  :network-manager-observe  -
raw-usb                  cups:raw-usb                  :raw-usb                  -
system-files             cups:etc-cups                 :system-files             -

# snap connections chromium
Schnittstelle             Plug                                    Slot                             Notizen
[...]
cups                      chromium:cups                           cups:cups                        manual
[...]
```

I have reinstalled the snaps und reconnected the cups manually but without success.

None snap applications just work fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried to run cups (snap) in stand-alone. Printers are showing up but still can't print.
https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-snap

`cups.lp -d <printer> <file>` shows error message with `file not found`

Comment: `Error - unable to access` is the correct error message. looks like snap-cups lacks permissions to access the filesystem too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I used a new driver PPD with an old printers.conf which caused the driver to crash when cups was running in proxy mode.

Added the printer through the web interface and replaced the new printers.conf in my ansible deployment.

works now.